# Handle gesture tap event in wp7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, gesture

I am little confuse how to handle gesture tap event?
When i tap my phone screen at that time gesture tap event fire two time automatically.But i want just one time

my code is

```
    var g1 = GestureService.GetGestureListener(TransactionList);
                g1.Tap += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs>(g1_Tap);
   g1.Hold += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs>(g1_Hold);



        void g1_Hold(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }     
        void g1_Tap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
            {
                ListBox hi = (ListBox)sender;
                ClsGetNewCampaign cg = (ClsGetNewCampaign)hi.SelectedItem;
                ClsGetNewCampaign.setlst(cg.cmpLoutAry);


                //int campaignId = Convert.ToInt32(cg.CampaignID);
                string campaignID = cg.CampaignID;
                string campaignName = cg.CampainNAME;
                string campaignImage = cg.CampainIMGPATH;
                string layoutTitle = cg.LayoutTitle;
                string layoutId = cg.LayoutID;


                //_ClsDatabase.Add_Data(campaignId, campaignName, campaignImage, layoutTitle, layoutId);

                string param = tbNew1.Text;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/VodafoneARview/Advertisement.xaml?parameter0={0},parameter1={1},parameter2={2},parameter3={3},parameter4={4},parameter5={5}", param,campaignID,campaignName,campaignImage,layoutTitle,layoutId), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


            }
```

Comment: You haven't accidentally added the event handler twice? i.e. once in the designer, and once with `g1.Tap += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs>(g1_Tap);`?

Comment: @Fabian:thanks it will working

Comment: Glad I could help. I just made that an answer to the question, if you could accept it that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment on your answer, make sure that you haven't accidentally added the event handler twice:

- once in the designer, and
- once in your code, on the line `g1.Tap += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs>(g1_Tap);`

That would explain why the event is firing twice :)